# How to get a list of user's groups using graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my FB app I'd like to get a list of groups (at least ID) user is member of. In graph API I found /v2.1/me/groups method but to use it I need user_groups permission. The problem is Facebook does not want to allow my app ask for this permission because:

> This permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client on platforms where Facebook is not already available.

So I cannot use it in my web application. Is there any other way to get a list of user's groups?

Comment: No, there's no other way.